# Linking IP to a domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, domain-name

This is a really newbie question but I need to ask in order to solve a doubt.

My situation is the classical one: I bought a domain name and I want to link it to an IP address. The easiest thing in the world (I believed).

I configured my DNS records in this way:

```
        IN NS     dns104.ovh.net.
        IN NS     ns104.ovh.net.
        IN A      95.141.40.2
www     IN CNAME  emarhost.net.
```

Well, it doesn't work! Also if I check by running the **dig** command will return this:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;emarhost.net.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
emarhost.net.       74271   IN  A   213.186.33.5
```

How is possible?

I thought the problem was that on IP 95.141.40.2 is running a TeamSpeak server and not a web server and then I tried to put the google.com IP but doesn't work at all.

Am I making any mistakes?

Thanks for help

Comment: It does work, though... `C:\>ping www.emarhost.net
Pinging emarhost.net [95.141.40.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 95.141.40.2: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=53` ?  As for "how is it possible", DNS caching - servers around the world will show you an answer for up to 48 hours before checking again to see if it's changed. Did www.emarhost.net point to 213.186.33.5 previously?

Comment: Yep the previous pointed ip was it. Then the problem is DNS caching...I feel so stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS server you queried cached the old record for an unusually long amount of time.

You can see that the cached record has 74271 seconds (about 20 hours 37 minutes) remaining before it expires. After that time, the DNS server will try your server again and get your new record.

Interestingly, I noted that the TTL for your new records is 21600 seconds (6 hours).

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.emarhost.net.       21600   IN      CNAME   emarhost.net.
emarhost.net.           21600   IN      A       95.141.40.2
```

Comment: The problem then is only the DNS caching. Understood. Now I feel a little embarrassed for the stupid question. My TTL is good or bad? I don't understand

Comment: The question is, can I make the actual TTL short in order to update the IP as soon as possible?

Comment: @Emar No, you could only have changed the TTL before the DNS record change.  And even then you would have had to wait for the old TTL to expire.

Comment: @Teddy Thanks, understand and solved changing my DNSs ;)